# How to focus an active window on .Net Maui Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, maui, winui-3

I have a .Net Maui application that runs on iOS, Android and Windows and receives push notifications.

On Windows, when I click a notification nothing happens.

I would like to "raise" the active instance that is opened, something like `window.Focus()` when a notification is clicked.

The way it was made in Xamarin Forms:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active.
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page.
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application.
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window.
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter.
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
    }

    // Ensure the current window is active.
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

I found examples but in all of them the App class inherits from Application which is not the case on Maui since it inherits from MauiWinUIApplication.

My App.xamls.cs:

```
public partial class App : MauiWinUIApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private readonly SingleInstanceDesktopApp _singleInstanceApp;
    LaunchActivatedEventArgs incomeArgs;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _singleInstanceApp = new SingleInstanceDesktopApp("GIKI");
        _singleInstanceApp.Launched += OnSingleInstanceLaunched;
    }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        incomeArgs = args;
        _singleInstanceApp.Launch(args.Arguments);
    }

    private void OnSingleInstanceLaunched(object? sender, SingleInstanceLaunchEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.IsFirstLaunch)
            {
                base.OnLaunched(incomeArgs);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
        }
    }

    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

The `OnSingleINstanceLauched` method is working. What next, on "else" to show the window in case it is in background, for example?

Comment: Click on MauiWinUIApplication. F12 to go to definition. That should open a window showing declaration of MauiWinUIApplication. Notice that it inherits from Application. So, it is still an Application. AFAIK, You should be able to use the Application examples you found.

Comment: I try to use the code in the maui. And the Window.Current always be null. In addition, all the properties of the MauiWinUIApplication are null. But when I called the `base.OnLaunched`, `this.Application` will have value. And there is a api named `AppInstance.GetCurrent();`, you may can use it do something.

Answer (score 0):

Not diving into your code, instead of "`protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)`" you could use Maui

```
builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(AppLifecycle =>
        {

#if WINDOWS

            AppLifecycle.AddEvent<OnLaunched>("OnLaunched", (Application application, LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) =>
            {

            //do your stuff

            });

#endif

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing several incomplete leads including some from Xamarin Forms this was what I found to work.

My particular use case was restoring focus to my app after authenticating using easy auth via protocol activation from a web page.  It also resolved a problem I had with PopModalAsync failing to navigate back from a Login page.

In MauiProgram.cs:

```
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
#if WINDOWS
                .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
                {                    
                    events.AddWindows(windows => windows.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                    {
                        YourNamespace.WinUI.Program.CurrentWindow = window as MauiWinUIWindow;
                    }));
                })
#endif
```

Then in Windows\Platform\Program.cs  (This could also be in Windows\Platform\App.xaml.cs if you did not implement Program.cs)

```
public class Program
{
    public static MauiWinUIWindow? CurrentWindow { get; set; }

    public static void ActivateApplication()
    {
        if (Program.CurrentWindow != null)
        {
            Program.SetForegroundWindow(Program.CurrentWindow.WindowHandle);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Now you can call YourNamespace.WinUI.Program.ActivateApplication() from any place in your Windows MAUI app.